# Exists point c such that property

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$. Show if $f$ is continous, exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}$.

I tried with Bonzano Weierstrass but not kinda work..

Comment: Bonzano, made me chuckle

Comment: Do you have any ideea?

Comment: You already tagged the question with [continuity], so perhaps you should add that assumption to the problem statement.

Comment: Try looking at function $H(x)=f(x)-x/(1-x)$.Then try Bolzano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivially false without any assumption on $f$ except that it is a positive function on $\mathbb R$. (Can you write down a counter-example?).

I will give a proof assuming that $f$ is continuous. Let $g(x)=(1-x)f(x)-x$. Then $g(1)=-1$ and $g(0)=f(0) \geq 0$. By IVP there exists $\alpha $ such that 
$g(\alpha)=0$. Since $\alpha \neq 1$ we can write this as $f(\alpha)=\frac {\alpha} {1-\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = {x \over 1-x}+1$ for $ x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x\ge 1$.

Then there is no $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha) = {\alpha \over 1-\alpha}$.

Comment: Given that the question is tagged with [continuity] I would assume that this assumption is just missing in the problem statement.

Comment: @MartinR: Me too, but I am tired of dealing with questions with missing information.

Comment: f is continous, sorry.